# PHP mcrypt & Perl Crypt::CBC generating different ciphertext

Tags: php, perl, encryption, aes

I am trying to learn various encryption methods and came across a problem when trying to generate ciphertext with Perl vs PHP.

If I encrypt a secret with PHP, I can decrypt the resulting ciphertext in both PHP and Perl, but if I encrypt in Perl the ciphertext is 'wrong' and the secret gets garbled by both PHP and Perl...

encrypt.php:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

# Set up vars   
$iv = 'length16length16';
$key = 'length32length32length32length32';
$cleartext = 'password';

if( count( $argv ) > 1 )
{
    $cleartext = $argv[1];
}
# --- ENCRYPTION ---
# Set up cipher
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
mcrypt_generic_init( $cipher, $key, $iv );

# Do the encryption
$ciphertext = mcrypt_generic( $cipher, $cleartext );

# Convert to HEX for print/storage
$cipher_block = implode( unpack( 'H*', $iv . $ciphertext ) );

print( "IV " . implode( unpack( 'H*', $iv ) ) );
print( "CIPH " . implode( unpack( 'H*', $ciphertext ) ) );
print( $cipher_block );

# Clean up
mcrypt_generic_deinit( $cipher );
mcrypt_module_close( $cipher );

?>
```

decrypt.php:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

# Set up vars
$key = 'length32length32length32length32';

if( count( $argv ) > 1 )
{
    # --- DECRYPTION ---
    # Grab the hex-encoded cipherblock & convert it to binary
    $cipher_block = unpack( 'a16iv/a*ciphertext', pack( 'H*', $argv[1] ) );

    # Set up cipher
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

    mcrypt_generic_init( $cipher, $key, $cipher_block['iv'] );

    # Do the decryption
    $cleartext = mdecrypt_generic( $cipher, $cipher_block['ciphertext'] );

    print( $cleartext );

    # Clean up
    mcrypt_generic_deinit( $cipher );
    mcrypt_module_close( $cipher );
}

?>
```

encrypt.pl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Crypt::CBC;

# Set up vars
my $iv = 'length16length16';
my $key = 'length32length32length32length32';
my $cleartext = shift;

# --- ENCRYPTION ---
# Set up cipher
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -literal_key    => 1,
    -key            => $key,
    -header         => 'none',
    -iv             => $iv,
    -cipher         => 'Crypt::OpenSSL::AES');

# Do the encryption
my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt( $cleartext );

# Convert to HEX for print/storage
my $cipher_block = unpack( 'H*', $iv . $ciphertext );

print( "IV " . unpack( 'H*', $iv ) . "\n" );
print( "CIPH " . unpack( 'H*', $ciphertext ) . "\n" );
print( $cipher_block );
```

decrypt.pl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Crypt::CBC;

# Set up vars
my $key = 'length32length32length32length32';

my $cipher_block = shift;

if( $cipher_block )
{
    # --- DECRYPTION ---
    # Grab the hex-encoded cipherblock & convert it to binary
    my ($iv, $ciphertext) = unpack( 'a16a*', pack( 'H*', $cipher_block ) );

    # Set up cipher
    my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
        -literal_key    => 1,
        -key            => $key,
        -header         => 'none',
        -iv             => $iv,
        -cipher         => 'Crypt::OpenSSL::AES');

    my $cleartext = $cipher->decrypt( $ciphertext );

    print( $cleartext );
}
```

And this is the output I get:

```sh
$ ./encrypt.php "Secret Text"
IV 6c656e67746831366c656e6774683136
CIPH 32a47901313f47ed2ca657d3bd0c2e80
6c656e67746831366c656e677468313632a47901313f47ed2ca657d3bd0c2e80

$ ./decrypt.php 6c656e67746831366c656e677468313632a47901313f47ed2ca657d3bd0c2e80
Secret Text

$ ./decrypt.pl 6c656e67746831366c656e677468313632a47901313f47ed2ca657d3bd0c2e80
Secret Text

$ ./encrypt.pl "Secret Text"
IV 6c656e67746831366c656e6774683136
CIPH f3ae0d5f236cea77fa9ac5540d733aef
6c656e67746831366c656e677468313632a47901313f47ed2ca657d3bd0c2e80

$ ./decrypt.php 6c656e67746831366c656e677468313632a47901313f47ed2ca657d3bd0c2e80
sesswrtext

$ ./decrypt.pl 6c656e67746831366c656e677468313632a47901313f47ed2ca657d3bd0c2e80
sesswrtext
```

As you can see, even with an identical secret, key & IV, the Perl script generates a distinct ciphertext, that the PHP & Perl scripts both decrypt to be the same, but not the original secret...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try not printing the output, but instead converting it to hex and then outputting it. I have a feeling there are trailing characters at play here (padding). They would be null bytes or low-bytes (unprintable) depending on which mode is used...

Comment: In both the encryption scripts I'm packing the ciphertext into a hex string before output for this reason :D

Comment: I'm not worried about the ciphertext, I'm worried about the plain text after decryption (not having the padding stripped properly)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is padding. Try:

```
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -literal_key    => 1,
    -key            => $key,
    -header         => 'none',
    -iv             => $iv,
    -padding        => 'null', #!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    -cipher         => 'Crypt::OpenSSL::AES');
```

and you should get:

```
CIPH 32a47901313f47ed2ca657d3bd0c2e80
```

Anyway `-padding=>'null'` might not be a good idea. Try to find out whether PHP's mcrypt supports most frequently used  PKCS#5/7 padding which corresponds to Crypt::CBC's `-padding=>'standard'`

Comment: PHP's mcrypt does not support that padding. You will have to do this yourself; there are some implementations in the comments of `mcrypt_encrypt`. Also note for `Crypt::OpenSSL::AES`: "Encrypt data. The size of $data must be exactly blocksize in length (16 bytes), otherwise this function will croak." I've tried it but my computer won't croak. Documentation must also be version 0.1 or so.